# Android Bundle with multi lingual string files in a apk

Tags: android, android-studio, localization, google-play, bundle

I want to release android bundle with multilingual string files so that whenever apk created from bundle it has all the string files. Because my app changed the language run time with the code and by default, google play download packaged apk with the string files based on the user device language. They also suggest to download the string file as a module but my app feature so that the first step is to select the language after that complete app works in selected language, I can't hold the user by the time string file download. Any will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution (not preferred way) is to add the

```
bundle {
        language {
            // Specifies that the app bundle should not support
            // configuration APKs for language resources. These
            // resources are instead packaged with each base and
            // dynamic feature APK.
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
```

in Gradle file, it will include all the localized string file in each apk, I hope this will solve the problem facing by the developers who want to change the app language run time.